# mysql Workbench table data import wizard decoding issue

Tags: mysql

I have saved my file to csv using:

```
pd.to_csv('path.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

And then try to use table data import wizard to import data to mysql talbe. I have aligned every column, but got the decoding error.
Attached is the pic, my question is:
Is there a way to specify mysql workbench's encoding setting？ My workbench version is: 5.7
[image: Decoding Error]

Solutions I have tried, but it doesn't work:

1. Open and save the file as .csv using mac numbers, ensure the encoding is utf-8

Comment: what is the content of your csv file? do it contains non-ascii characters?

Comment: yes, it has. but I want to use utf-8 for the sql importing, why is it using ascii to decode the file?